# Symfony Twig Embedded Forms: the rendered prototype has the wrong format and leads to an error when submitting

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I am struggling with using the prototype to add a new entity to a one to many relation using a form. There are members having multiple email addresses. When the prototype is rendered in the browser, it differs from already filled form fields, which leads to an error when submitting the form (form invalid). I could potentially fix that in the javascript, but assume I have made an error somehow. But dont know where.

Rendered in the browser:

existing field:

```
<input type="text" id="member_mails_4_mail" name="member[mails][4][mail]" maxlength="30" class="form-control" value="e@mail.de">
```

new field created by JS:

```
<input type="email" id="member_mails_5" name="member[mails][5]" required="required" class="form-control">
```

The prototype in the TWIG template

```
<h3>Registered Mails</h3>
                        <ul class="mails"
                            data-index="{{ memberForm.mails|length > 0 ?    memberForm.mails|last.vars.name + 1 : 0 }}"
                            data-prototype="{{ form_row(memberForm.mails.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"
                        >

                            {% for mailForm in memberForm.mails %}
                                <li>{{ form_row(mailForm.mail) }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    <button type="button" class="add_mails_link" data-collection-holder-class="mails">Add a mail address
                    </button>
```

The javascript to add the new input field:

```
const addMailForm = (e) => {
    const collectionHolder = document.querySelector('.' + e.currentTarget.dataset.collectionHolderClass);

    const item = document.createElement('li');

    item.innerHTML = collectionHolder
        .dataset
        .prototype
        .replace(
            /__name__/g,
            collectionHolder.dataset.index
        );

    collectionHolder.appendChild(item);

    collectionHolder.dataset.index++;
};
```

The member type:

```
 $builder->add('mails', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => EmailType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            'prototype' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ]);
```

The email type:

```
class EmailType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('mail');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Mail::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I adapted the newly created input field in the browser that the schema matches the existing ones, then submitting works. I would expect that the prototype is rendered like the already filled input fields.